# How to download, then delete file in ASP.NET properly?

Tags: asp.net, file, downloading-website-files

I've stumbled upon this problem recently: In my app, I'm providing users with the option of downloading multiple files from a list by putting them into a .zip folder and then downloading that. I naturally want that .zip folder to be deleted once the download is finished. Here's my approach:

```
       try {

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.zip");
            Response.TransmitFile(archive);
            Response.Flush();
            success = success && true;

            return success;

        } catch {

            return false;

        } finally {

            System.IO.File.Delete(archive);
            Response.End();

        }
```

Now, the booleans are just to indicate whether or not was the download successful and I don't think they are important right now. 
I thought how this works is the program first tries to transmit the file to the client, if no errors occur it skips the catch block and only *after* it was downloaded will it delete the `archive` file.

However, I am often getting an error saying `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` on the line `System.IO.File.Delete(archive);`. This doesn't happen every time, as far as I can see, it's rather random. 
Could anyone hint me at the solution?

Comment: don't use `Response.TransmitFile` but rather open and send manually the file, also close the connection before you delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=myFile.txt");
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/myFile.txt"));
    Response.Flush();
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/myFile.txt"));
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see what happens :)